# How to create delete button on image and add its functionality

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm fresher in coding so that I need your help.I hope that you are going to help me.

I created a database and retrieve images from the database to PHP file and getting an error while I try to add delete button which is going to delete the image from a database. Below was my code, please help me to add delete button and it's functionality :

```
<section class="content">
     <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="gallery">

          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="header">
                    <h2>
                        GALLERY
   <!--<small>All pictures taken from <a href="https://unsplash.com/" target="_blank">unsplash.com</a></small>-->
                     </h2>
                       <hr/>

    <div class="body">
          <div id="aniimated-thumbnials" class="list-unstyled row clearfix">

            <?php
            //Include database configuration file
            include('db_upload_dashboard.php');

            //get images from database
            $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM upload_img ORDER BY uploaded_on DESC");

            if($query->num_rows > 0){
                while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){

                    $imageThumbURL = 'images/thumb/'.$row["file_name"];
                    $imageURL = 'images/'.$row["file_name"];
            ?>
```

//Please help me to add delete button here

```
<button id="delete"> Delete
                    <a href="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>"  data-fancybox="group" data-caption="<?php echo $row["title"]; ?>" >
                        <img src="<?php echo $imageThumbURL; ?>" alt="" />
                    </a>
         </button>
                <?php }
                } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: could you edit so we can have the code where you tried to add the button and got an error, instead of having the working code without it? Adding the error itself would help too. This will make us understand better what you are trying to do

Comment: What error you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

HTML forbids nesting links inside buttons.

Start by writing valid, semantic HTML that says what you mean.

---

You want to make an HTTP request that changes your database. That means you need a POST request. That means you need a form. So start there.

```
<form method="POST" action="/delete-image.php">

</form>
```

You want a button which triggers the action.

```
<form method="POST" action="/delete-image.php">
    <button>Delete</button> <!-- submit is the default type of button -->
</form>
```

You need to pass data describing which image you want to delete:

```
<form method="POST" action="/delete-image.php">
    <button name="delete" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['id']); ?>">
        Delete
    </button>
</form>
```

You want to show the image in the button

```
<form method="POST" action="/delete-image.php">
    <button name="delete" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['id']); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($imageThumbURL)" alt="">
    </button>
</form>
```

Then you need to delete it from the database when the form is submitted:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        show_an_error();
        exit();
    }
    $row_id_to_delete = $_POST['delete'];
    # Database query code left as an exercise to the reader
```